# Scheduling/Refiling Trouble with org-gcal / org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-capture

I'm using org-gcal with org-agenda.

Because org-gcal seems to strip entries of any TODO markers, I would like to create entries in my org-gcal synced file by using refile to copy over entries from my to-do list file.

However, when I refile an entry with a SCHEDULED: time-stamp into my org-gcal synced file, I get two time stamps in the resulting entry.

For example I start with an entry in my to-do list file that looks like

```
* Demo trouble with refile
  SCHEDULED: <2017-07-15 Sat>
```

Then I refile it to my org-gcal sync file, I get

```
* Demo trouble with refile
  :PROPERTIES:
  :LINK: [[https://www.google.com/calendar/event?HIDDEN][Go to gcal web page]]
  :ID: vrvehri7aa1lktb6u1aee15roc
  :END:

  <2017-07-15 Sat>

  SCHEDULED: <2017-07-15 Sat>
```

And the two time stamps cause the entry to show up twice in my agenda view.

However, if I start without an entry with a time stamp that has no SCHEDULED: prefix, then things work better.
For example, if I start with

```
* Demo no trouble with refile 
  <2017-07-15 Sat>
```

Then after refiling to my org-gcal synced file I get

```
* Demo no trouble with refile
  :PROPERTIES:
  :LINK: [[https://www.google.com/calendar/event?HIDDEN][Go to gcal web page]]
  :ID: 4irlnqb3g1u6nv29gq9tiockbk
  :END:

  <2017-07-15 Sat>
```

I can imagine at least two ways of fixing my issue. One would be if I could stop the "C-c C-s" scheduling command from adding the SCHEDULED: prefix before the time stamp.
Another solution would be if I could make the refile command automatically reformat the entry before inserting it into the org-gcal synced file.

Currently, to get around the problem I'm adding time stamps by going to the agenda file and using "C-c ." to get around the problem, but this is very unsatisfactory.